# переместить часть таблицы по условию в конец выдачи

Tags: sql

Есть запрос по результату которого формируется таблица примерно вида

```
name  0
name2 0
name3 0
name4 4
name5 6
....
```

отсортирована по возрастанию
но нужно чтобы нули были в конце таблицы т.е результат должен быть примерно

```
name4 4
name5 6
name  0
name2 0
name3 0
```

подскажите пожалуйста как или хотя бы в каком направлении копать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Был где-то такой вопрос, если коротко, можно как-то так: `...order by \`field\` = 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для многих СУБД подойдет подобная конструкция

```
select name,num
  from tableX
 order by case when num=0 then 1 else 0 end, num, name
```

Или используйте вместо case какую нибудь другую функцию, заменяющую case в вашей СУБД. Функция должна выдать 1 если запись должна быть в конце и 0 если с обычной сортировкой

Comment: всё же, лучше добавить `name` третьим столбцом в сортировку